# Read BSON file in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, bson

I want to read a BSON format Mongo dump in Python and process the data. I am using the Python [bson package](https://github.com/martinkou/bson) (which I'd prefer to use rather than have a pymongo dependency), but it doesn't explain how to read from a file.

This is what I'm trying:

```
bson_file = open('statistics.bson', 'rb')
b = bson.loads(bson_file)
print b[0]
```

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    b = bson.loads(bson_file)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bson/__init__.py", line 75, in loads
    return decode_document(data, 0)[1]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bson/codec.py", line 235, in decode_document
    length = struct.unpack("<i", data[base:base + 4])[0]
TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it does not appear that bson.loads expects a file.

Comment: (as clearly indicated in the documentation of the `loads` method.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation states :

```
> help(bson.loads)
Given a BSON string, outputs a dict.
```

You need to pass a string. For example:

```
> b = bson.loads(bson_file.read())
```

Comment: I need this for the quite normal example of a bson file with multiple lines, where I thus use .readlines() instead of .read(). This throws an error. At best, answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474479/bson-file-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: do you mean multiple bson objects in the file, one per line? would `b = [bson.loads(line) for line in bson_file.readlines()]` work in that case?

Comment: Throws error: `[pybson.loads(line) for line in open(filename,'rb').readlines()]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pybson\__init__.py", line 47, in loads
    return decode_document(data, 0)[1]
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pybson\codec.py", line 277, in decode_document
    if data[end_point - 1] not in ('\0', 0):
IndexError: index out of range`

Comment: I have installed and imported it with `import pybson` as that can be differenciated from pymongo `import bson`, see https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/70. Your `import bson` is the same as long as you do not have pymongo installed (as pymongo `import bson` dominates).

Comment: readlines() does not split the string correctly, what is needed is 
`with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    b = f.read()
listStrByte = re.split(rb'(?!\A)(?=\\!)', b)
print(len(listStrByte))
listBs = []
for i in listStrByte[:2]:
        listBs.append(pybson.loads(i))
`
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591863/split-a-string-and-keep-the-delimiters-as-part-of-the-split-string-chunks-not-a for details about this regex split.

I stopped the loop at [:2], take this constraint away after tests. My limited pc crashed at [:9], thus I use the easier pymongo now, see the pymongo answer.

Comment: this will give an attribute error. bson doesnt support loads. I tried running it and got an error like: AttributeError: module 'bson' has no attribute 'loads'

Comment: But how do you define the bson_file?

Comment: @seeker_after_truth that's just any file-like object

Comment: @njk2, thank you, but what actually is a "file-like object" / where can I go to learn more about what this is?

Comment: @PujaBhattacharya I'm getting the same error (AttributeError: module 'bson' has no attribute 'loads'). Is the problem that there are 2 bson packages and we are using a different one from @njzk2?

Comment: https://github.com/py-bson/bson not much ambiguity there

Answer (score 16):

I found this worked for me with a mongodb 2.4 BSON file and *PyMongo*'s 'bson' module:

```
import bson
with open('survey.bson','rb') as f:
    data = bson.decode_all(f.read())
```

That returned a list of dictionaries matching the JSON documents stored in that mongo collection.

The f.read() data looks like this in a BSON:

```
>>> rawdata[:100]
'\x04\x01\x00\x00\x12_id\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02_type\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00simple\x00\tchanged\x00\xd0\xbb\xb2\x9eI\x01\x00\x00\tcreated\x00\xd0L\xdcfI\x01\x00\x00\x02description\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00testing the bu'
```

Comment: but the approved answer is a better way to go

Comment: In oder to use the code of this answer, you need to use `pip install pymongo` instead of `pip install bson` = `pip install pybson`. Both have the `import bson` statement. See https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/70

Comment: @Max Maxmeister Up to now, the other answer's example does not help me with the quite normal case of a file with multiple lines of a mongodb bson dump file, and unless that is not answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474479/bson-file-to-pandas-dataframe, the other answer is not just a better way to go.

Comment: @Lorenz I consider `bson.loads` better because that function was designed for this exact use case. My answer deals with the raw data, and I suppose it may be more flexible if you're loading something that is not properly encoded. IF you need to load each line in file separately, you might try the `bson.loads` on each line instead?

Comment: **pybson**'s `bson.loads` seems to be complicating things as soon as you have multiple lines. See the comments on the pybson answer. At least from what I have experienced in practice. Your answer with the **pymongo**'s `import bson` works fine.

Comment: I do not understand why my edit of the answer was not accepted. "Trusted SO members" had to decide this, and they ignored the edit. bson module exists both in pymongo package and in bson package. The current expression "python's bson module" of this answer here has cost me several hours to find out that this answer is not based on the bson package as the other answer is. (That is why I have asked bson to also offer its package under another name, which is now done with pybson, see again https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/70)

Answer (score 2):

`loads` expects a string (that's what the 's' stands for), not a file. Try reading from the file, and passing the result to `loads`.