# How to loop through a folder and save files as a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, file, operating-system

So I have a folder with 30 something .bson files and i can access them one by one by using this code:

```
    path_to_bson = 'C:/Documents/dump2020/strat_db/xyz.bson'
    data=[]
    with open(path_to_bson,'rb') as f:
        data=bson.decode_all(f.read())
    xyz=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried accessing all the files together but dont know how to get further:

```
   path_to_bson = 'C:/Documents/dump2020/strat_db'
   bson_files=[pos_bson for pos_bson in os.listdir(path_to_bson) if pos_bson.endswith('.bson')]        
   data=[]
   for bs in bson_files:
       with open(//what should be here?//,'rb') as f:
            //what should be here?//
```

I want the dataframe's name to be same as the .bson file. So for instance, xyz.bson should be saved as a dataframe named xyz and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open and decode the bson files, then convert them to a pandas df.

Using the answer in this post ([BSON file to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474479/bson-file-to-pandas-dataframe)) I think you need something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import bson
import os

path_to_bson = 'C:/Documents/dump2020/strat_db'
bson_files=[pos_bson for pos_bson in os.listdir(path_to_bson) if pos_bson.endswith('.bson')]        

for bs in bson_files:
     fileloc = path_to_bson + "\\" + bs
     with open(fileloc,'rb') as f:
           data = bson.decode_all(f.read())

     main_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

     saveloc = os.path.splitext(fileloc)[0] + ".pkl"
     main_df.to_pickle(saveloc)
```

Comment: main_df should be the name of the .bson file ( bs in bson_files). I dont know how to do that. Also this code is just returning the last .bson file as a dataframe

Comment: I had the save line indented incorrectly in the `with` . The line `saveloc = os.path.splitext(fileloc)[0] + ".pkl"` should be taking the name of the opened .bson file