# Why is BytesIO not splitting binary file correctly by newlines?

Tags: python, bson

I have a BytesIO buffer into which is being written the contents of a file in S3. That file has [pybson](https://github.com/py-bson/bson) BSON objects written to it, separated by `\n` characters, i.e. binary characters separated by new lines.

I want to parse the event objects in the file. I am iterating through each line like this:

```
def iter_event(data: BytesIO):
    for line in data:
        yield bson.loads(line)
```

I am finding that there seem to be some rogue characters being injected or corrupted at the end of the `line` variable in some cases and my code is failing with the same exception as mentioned briefly in one of the comments in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27528088/272023). When I look at the file using a binary editor I cannot see the rogue character, it seems to only occur in the `line` variable.  (For what it's worth, the end of the BSON object looks like `\x00\x00\n` in a binary editor and my line variable ends in `\x00\x10e\n`.

Is there an issue with iterating through each line like this? If not, what's a better approach please?

Comment: Do you have a short but complete program to share? Maybe the bug is somewhere else, not in BytesIO.

Comment: For debugging, you may want to `print(type(data))`, `print(type(line))` (it should be `bytes`, not `str`) and `print(len(line))`. Please post the debug output.

Comment: "BSON objects separated by `\n` characters" is a completely unworkable data format - most of the BSON data types can contain a newline character in their representation.  But you don't actually need a separator, as BSON data starts with a length, which could be used to unambiguously split up a stream into the original objects.  I'm not familiar with the library you're using, so I can't suggest how you could best implement that.

Comment: BSON is a binary format. So append a BSON object to the file with a header which includes the size of the body BSON bytes. Then parse the file sequentially. It's easy with the standard ```struct``` module.